# Refresh image after change with fileupload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, refresh

I'm trying to refresh image after upload it in a "my account page".

I tried the following way but didn't work "completely": [Is there a way to refresh an image after an ajax file upload in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228149/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-an-image-after-an-ajax-file-upload-in-jquery)

Look to what happens:

1. Code to refresh after back to view: `<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageUrl + (Model.Imagem.Updated ? "?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks : string.Empty)" />`
2. I upload image with fileupload;
3. The image is updated, but if I access another page, and back to "my account page" again, the image is not updated (only works if I press ctrl + f5);